# CodeIgniter: How to send a javascript variable to contoller and back to the view?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to achieve live updating on variables in my viewers and It is almost done. The problem is that I want to compare the result now from the variable so I can print one message or another. I am using **append** to put the result into a div and echo it to show the number of comments but I can't get it to compare with the if statement in the file.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){get_msg_count()}, 1000);
    function get_msg_count() {
    $.ajax ({
        data: {}, // not really needed
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '<?php echo site_url("blog/getCommentCount");?>', // page to return your msg count
        success: function(response) {
            $('#noOfComments').html(response); 
            }
        }); // End $.ajax
    } // End Function
 </script>
```

Here is the view for the comments: Where it is the actual problem of trying to compare the variable.

```
<h2>Comments - {<div class="noOfComments" id="noOfComments"></div>}</h2>

    <?php $variable = '<div id="noOfComments</div>' ?>
    <?php if ($variable >= 1): ?>
    <div class="comment-box">
      <div id="responds"></div>
      {comments}
      <div class="single-comment">
          <h5>{name}</h5><span class="pubdate"> - {pubdate}</span>
          <hr/>
          <p>{comment}</p>
      </div>
      {/comments}
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      Sorry, I didn't manage to find any comments :(
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and this is the controller:

```
  public function getCommentCount()
   {
     $comments = new Comment_model();
     $noOfComments = $comments->where('blog_id', '2')->count(); 
     echo json_encode($noOfComments);
   }
```

Any ideas how to send it to the file and use the variable ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your response for json data.

controller

```
public function getCommentCount()
{
   $comments = new Comment_model();
   $noOfComments = $comments->where('blog_id', '2')->count();
   /**
   *    declare ajax data here
   *    if your $noOfComments will show value
   *    ex : $noOfComments = 10
   */
   $result['comments_count'] = $noOfComments;
   echo json_encode($noOfComments);
}
```

And the javascript

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#noOfComments').html(response.comments_count); 
}
```